# How can I get selenium/cucumber to interact with a "hidden" link that is now in a lightbox/colorbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, colorbox

I'm using the colorbox library to display lightboxes within my application (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/). The code seems to work fine in the browser, but I'm having trouble getting the automated test to work.

Here is some inline HTML that gets generated:

```
<div class='hidden'>
  <div id='override'>
    Are you sure you want to override this action?
    <br>
      <a href="" class="close_colorbox">Cancel</a></li>
      <a href="#" onclick="override(this); return false;">Override once</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript that opens the colorbox:

```
$.fn.colorbox({innerWidth:600, inline:true, href:'#override', scrolling:false});
```

That code opens the lightbox and display the contents of my '#override' div. In my cucumber tests I can find text from inside that div, but I get an error if I try to follow a link:

```
  When I follow "link that generates override"    
  Then I should see "Are you sure you want to override this action?" within "#cboxContent"
  Then I should see "Cancel" within "#cboxContent"
  # Then show me the page
  When I follow "Cancel" within "#cboxContent"
```

Gives this error:

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotDisplayedError)
[remote server] resource://fxdriver/modules/atoms.js:7903:in `'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/nn/nn5oYAICGPawlH+1W406+k+++TI/-Tmp-/webdriver-profile20110524-2973-1d5qq7w/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/nsCommandProcessor.js:249:in `'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/nn/nn5oYAICGPawlH+1W406+k+++TI/-Tmp-/webdriver-profile20110524-2973-1d5qq7w/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/nsCommandProcessor.js:298:in `'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/nn/nn5oYAICGPawlH+1W406+k+++TI/-Tmp-/webdriver-profile20110524-2973-1d5qq7w/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/nsCommandProcessor.js:313:in `'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/nn/nn5oYAICGPawlH+1W406+k+++TI/-Tmp-/webdriver-profile20110524-2973-1d5qq7w/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/nsCommandProcessor.js:190:in `'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:35
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in `with_scope'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in `with_scope'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:34:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
features/prerequisites.feature:38:in `When I follow "Cancel" within "#cboxContent"'
```

Has anyone seen this error before and how did you get around it? (If I uncomment the 'show me the page' step then it also works)

Comment: It seems like the $.fn.colorbox call isn't finishing by the time I try to follow the Cancel link (so it is still hidden inside the other div). I'm trying to figure out the best way to make capybara/selenium wait for the div to become visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having a similar issue with the Jquery-mobile framework.

From what I understand, Capybara is supposed to wait until all the AJAX calls are completed before doing a check or moving on.  However, if you are having an issue where you think the page isn't finished loading you could try adding a simple "sleep 1" to Capybara's stock "I press" step to see if that helps.

Comment: Yes - sleep 1 also works. I think the problem is that the colorbox has an animation step that takes a few milliseconds - so the ajax call is done, but the animation isn't. I think the right answer should be somehow using the selenium.wait_for_condition, but I can't figure out how to call it in my cucumber steps ("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementById('colorbox').style.display == 'block'"). I will probably have a lot of these steps for my entire test suite and the sleep 1s will start to add up!